# After selecting all from a certain row, is there a way to grab data from certain columns not defined?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So my SELECT statement is selecting all from a row in the users table. There is a column in that row labeled "user_level" and I want to use the data from that column to differentiate between an admin and a guest. Is there a way to use "user_level" (and maybe bind it to a session variable) without me having to write another SELECT statement?

```
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
        $error = 'All fields are required!';
    } else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :name and
 user_password = :password");

        $query->bindValue(":name", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $query->execute();

        $num = $query->rowCount();

        if ($num == 1) {
            //user entered correct details
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            //user entered false details
            $error = 'Incorrect details!';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you return the query as an array rather than counting it, and do an `if ($result['user_level'] > 0)` ? Check the array exists to make sure they are logged in.

Comment: @YourCommonSense A little presumptuous, don't you think? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need no rowCount here.
as well as half of the duplicated and triplicated code.

```
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_name = ? and user_password = ?";
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $srm->execute(array($username,$password));
    $level = $stm->fetchColumn();
    if ($level !== FALSE) {
        //user entered correct details
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $level;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}
$error = 'Incorrect details!';
```

Comment: Won't that fail to log them in if they have a user level of 0?